# embeding an image in a cdf deployment

Tags: import, image, cdf-format

I would like to embed an image into CDF. Import function just import the function from a pathway but I would like the image to be present in the CDF or nb file as a part of it not importing.

ImageResize[
 Import["/Users/mac1/Desktop/Logosmall.jpg"], {100}]

This requires file to be in this path but the computers that CDF will be used wont have this path or even the file.

Comment: You cannot read files into a deployed .cdf. But you can embed the images. Import the image in Mathematica. When you create the Manipulate function in the cdf, add the option `SaveDefinitions->True` and the image will be stored/saved along with the cdf.

Comment: http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/842760